# Submit form on <select> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

I am looking for a way to submit my form when I click a `<option>`.

Explanation of `<select>` use:
Click checkboxes and then choose what folder to move the ones that were selected to using the drop-down menu.

Here is what my form looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/yufwu/23/

Keep in mind the checkboxes have multiple uses (delete, move to folder).
And the drop-down menu (`<select>`) is retrieving the folders from the `folders` table.

I am having a hard time explaining this so if you have any questions just ask.

**EDIT:** Thanks to NullPointer I got this working. Exact code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function ()
    {
        $(this).closest('form[name="delete-volunteer-app"]').submit();
    });
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Comment: this is much harder than it sounds. Try navigating the select box via the keyboard. The `click` event is insufficient, you also need the `change` event. But that's only triggered when the user moves to another field. Also don't forget about accessibility users who may using a screen reader and/or may not have a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('option').click(function () //ill sugest to use the change  event 
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); //or $("form id or class or form[name="formname"]").submit();
});
```

Comment: in fact, click would not be the best option. For instance, if you move with the keyboard (Tab key), the click event is not detected, just the change event is the only sure (and just if you change the selected option)

Comment: Korcholis is right. You should use select onchange event to do this functionality!

Comment: @Korcholis you are right ... even the click is not supported by Safari

Comment: Thanks so much NullPointer. Works perfectly. I am using `change`. I will update my OP with the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#select').change(function(){    
        var select_val = $(this).val();   
        // make ajax hit for select value   
    })   
})
```

just submit the form or it is better to send ajax hit according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByName("folder")[0].onchange=function() {
    this.form.submit();
  }
}
```